# Uploaded File points to a directory using Laravel 4

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, laravel-4

When a user uploads an image under 1MB, everything works and the uploaded image is copied to another location. However when a larger file (~ 3 MB) is uploaded, I get the error

```
copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory
```

The line that threw this error was:

```
$src = Input::file('uploaded-photo')->getRealPath();
copy($src, $dest);
```

I echoed out `$src` and it gave me the root directory of the website

```
/var/www/dev/public
```

If I were to upload a small image file, `$src` is

```
/tmp/phpg1CjEu
```

I'm using PHP framework Laravel 4 on nginx 1.4.1

**Question:** How can the problem be fixed so larger sized photos work too?

Comment: What are the values in your php.ini for these: `memory_limit, 
upload_max_filesize,
post_max_size,` ?

Comment: `memory_limit = 128M`, `upload_max_filesize = 2M`, `post_max_size = 8M`. Aha!

Comment: Changed `upload_max_filesize = 30M`, `post_max_size = 30M` but still getting the same problem after reloading nginx and php5-fpm

Comment: Would this script make any difference when trying to upload a large file? `$file = Input::file('file'); 
$destinationPath = 'uploads/'.str_random(8);
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
//$extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);` . http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/uploading-files-in-laravel-4/ If it doesn't, the issue might be in the configuration somehwere

Comment: I get the error `Call to a member function move() on a non-object`

Comment: Your file is named 'uploaded-photo' not 'file'. Have you changed that in the script? `Input::file('uploaded-photo')`

Comment: Thanks you caught the error. Seems like php.ini changes didnt take effect, getting the error `The file "IMG_0040.JPG" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 kb)` The changes I made were on `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`.

Comment: Great, I will post this as an answer then :)

Comment: Sorry I meant I'm still getting the error `The file "IMG_0040.JPG" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 kb)`

Comment: Then the issue is with refreshing the php.ini configuration, you should check with nginx and make sure it is not caching it or reading from somewhere else. But the reason is definitely the `upload_max_filesize` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini` file